# Drawing lines from pivot points that meet a specific conditions

Tags: arrays, pivot, line, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have successfully created a script that draws a line from one pivot point to another based on some conditions.

The conditions are:

1. The next (or following next) pivot points must have a high that is lower than the original pivot point high
2. The next (or following next) pivot points must have its wick "touching" the original wick
3. It is not allowed to draw a line if there is any higher high in the range between the original pivothigh wick and the current pivothigh wick. If several conditions are meet, a "fan of lines" from the original pivot high can be created.

I asked a question about this before here [Creating a fan of lines in pinescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686637/creating-a-fan-of-lines-in-pinescript)

I managed to do this using arrays. [Result can been seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXzot.png). Purple lines are "hand drawn" and the white dashed lines comes from the script.

So far so good. BUT I have 3 problems/issues:

1. When a new candle is created the script fails due to "range out of bounds". I know it comes from the var declarations of the arrays on lines 19-22. If on the 1h or above timeframe it's not a big issue but on 1m it's very annoying. But deleting the var it doesn't compile correctly.
2. It's slow. Takes a couple of seconds to compute even though I'm using a while statement that prevents the "lookback" if a "top" has been detected. Then it's no longer necessary to look back anymore.
3. Related to (2). I'm suspecting there is a much smarter way to do this in pinescript but I haven't figured it out yet without the use of arrays.

Here's the code.

Is it possible to do this without arrays to solve all my 3 issues above?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © sincereStork12718

//@version=5
indicator("Pivot lines", overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

//---------------------------------------
//Variable declaration
//---------------------------------------
nbrBars =  bar_index
plot (nbrBars, title = "nbrBars", display = display.data_window)
plot(last_bar_index, title = "last_bar_index", display = display.data_window)

//---------------------------------------
// Pivot to downside with ARRAYS working 99.9%
//---------------------------------------

//Declare arrays
var index_array_bear = array.new<int>(last_bar_index)
var high_array = array.new<float>(last_bar_index)
var upwick_array = array.new<float>(last_bar_index)
var shadow_high = array.new<float>(last_bar_index+1)

isAttFUBear = ta.pivothigh(1,1) // For this example ta.pivothigh(1,1) will produce the same result
isFUBear = ta.pivothigh(1,1) //For this example ta.pivothigh(1,1) will produce the same result

//Get bar_index, the high and the start of the upper wick for all AttFU/FU to the downside in the series from first to last bar
var i_dn = 0
if (isAttFUBear or isFUBear) == 1 
    array.set(index_array_bear, i_dn, bar_index[1])
    array.set(high_array, i_dn, high[1])
    array.set(upwick_array, i_dn, math.max(open[1], close[1]))
    i_dn += 1

var j_dn = 0
array.set(shadow_high, j_dn, high)
j_dn += 1

//Draw line from index n to all index n++ that satisfies the condition below
//1. n++ index must be lower than the n:th index, i.e. high[n++] < high[n]
//2. n++ index must have it's high above upwick of the n:th, i.e. high[n++] > upwick[n]
//3. There must be a filter that removes any high higher than high[n] and high[n++] to not draw any unneccesary lines, i.e. if a "top" is found is not longer neccecary to look backwards

cnt1 = 1
top_found = false
while i_dn >= 2 and i_dn-1-cnt1 >= 0 and top_found == false
    if array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1) > array.get(high_array, i_dn-1) //Checking if previous FU is higher than the current, if NOT, check the next previous etc.
        if array.get(high_array, i_dn-1) >= array.get(upwick_array, i_dn-1-cnt1) //Check if current high is retesting the wick of the previous
            //testing filter high in between
            high_in_range = array.new<float>(nbrBars) //Create temporary array that stores all high values between the first and last endpoints of the line
            for cnt2 = array.get(index_array_bear, i_dn-1-cnt1) to array.get(index_array_bear, i_dn-1)
                array.set(high_in_range, cnt2, array.get(shadow_high, cnt2))
            max_high_in_range = array.max(high_in_range, 2) //Return the second highest high within the range (excluding the i-1-cnt1 which is the higest)
            if array.get(high_array, i_dn-1) > max_high_in_range
                line.new(array.get(index_array_bear, i_dn-1-cnt1), array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1), array.get(index_array_bear, i_dn-1), array.get(high_array, i_dn-1), color = color.white, style = line.style_dashed, width = 1)
        if i_dn-1-cnt1-1 > 0 //Checking if current lookback FU is higher than previous and next. If true then stop the search
            if array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1) > array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1+1) and array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1) > array.get(high_array, i_dn-1-cnt1-1)
                top_found := true
    cnt1 := cnt1 +1
```

Comment: After reading a lot more in the reference manual and noticing how arrays are declared, I solved it!

Instead of 

    `var index_array_bear = array.new<int>(last_bar_index)`

 it's best (in my case) to define an array as

    `var index_array_bear = array.new<int>(0)`

And instead of using 

    `array.set(index_array_bear, i_dn, bar_index[1])`

I replaced it with

    `array.push(index_array_bear, bar_index[1])`

This solved my question

I'm a bit rusty after not coding for 20+ years. I know what I want to do but I'm sometimes stuck in thinking of older languages :)

Comment: @user3848207 what exactly do you need from this question? Is your problem exactly the same?

Comment: I solved all issues myself when I posted the latest comment